# Что не так с цветокоррекцией изображения после обработки imagick?

Tags: imagemagick, imagick

Конвертировал pdf в jpg с помощью команды `convert -quality 70 katalog.pdf img/katalog.jpg` . У получившихся файлов что-то не так с цветом. И именно при просмотре в браузере, а они как раз и нужны для просмотра на сайте. Прикладываю скрин: первое фото - это просмотр через стандартную программу windows (здесь все нормально), а второе - через браузер (здесь что-то не так с цветом). Что не так? Почему через стандартную программу windows все нормально, а через браузер нет? Как это можно пофиксить при следующей конвертации?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очевидно, что-то не так или с гаммой, или с цветовым профилем, или с обоими сразу. Без файла ответить что-то конкретное трудно (разве что кто-нибудь угадает)